# Accordion without Javascript just CSS

Tags: accordion

I already searched for similar problems, but couldnt find anything go get me further.

Im trying to get a pure CSS accordion working which should in the end exactly look like the one on the bottom of this page: http://atelier-rauen.de/wweber/, which i built with jQuery.

Now i want to build one which works when the browser has javascript disabled, but I just cant get the text to float next to the inputs. 
This is the one Im working on right now http://atelier-rauen.de/cssaccordion/

It should exactly work like the one I built with jQuery, so the buttons are a block and the text floats next to it and doenst move below the buttons.

Please help me guys, Im totally stressed out.

Thanks a lot in advance,
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Although not styled 100%, I've put together a simple CSS only vertical tab implementation that should help you out. You can also see a jsBin of what I've put together [here](http://jsbin.com/zacuponaja/edit?html,css,output).

The key is keeping your content panel absolutely positioned correctly with regards to label width on your tabs. You can always wrap the entire set of tabs within a wrapper and then position this within your page. You could also use percentages for your label width and content panel positioning.

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width : 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 102px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0px 30px 4px 0px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1> CSS Tabs </h1>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="tab">
      <input id='A' type="radio" name="nav" checked>
      <label for='A'>A</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Nostrud eu veniam elit qui ea minim reprehenderit sit dolore cillum sit aute quis. Sit nostrud ad nisi est incididunt commodo ut ex reprehenderit excepteur. Irure id deserunt nulla sint dolore cillum fugiat ad ea tempor Lorem. Aliquip ex ad ullamco adipisicing enim duis. Exercitation elit sit est duis sint officia duis ad aliqua eiusmod reprehenderit amet reprehenderit consequat. Mollit occaecat elit eiusmod nulla officia laborum pariatur veniam ea do.</p>
                <p>Nostrud eu veniam elit qui ea minim reprehenderit sit dolore cillum sit aute quis. Sit nostrud ad nisi est incididunt commodo ut ex reprehenderit excepteur. Irure id deserunt nulla sint dolore cillum fugiat ad ea tempor Lorem. Aliquip ex ad ullamco adipisicing enim duis. Exercitation elit sit est duis sint officia duis ad aliqua eiusmod reprehenderit amet reprehenderit consequat. Mollit occaecat elit eiusmod nulla officia laborum pariatur veniam ea do.</p>
                <p>Nostrud eu veniam elit qui ea minim reprehenderit sit dolore cillum sit aute quis. Sit nostrud ad nisi est incididunt commodo ut ex reprehenderit excepteur. Irure id deserunt nulla sint dolore cillum fugiat ad ea tempor Lorem. Aliquip ex ad ullamco adipisicing enim duis. Exercitation elit sit est duis sint officia duis ad aliqua eiusmod reprehenderit amet reprehenderit consequat. Mollit occaecat elit eiusmod nulla officia laborum pariatur veniam ea do.</p>
                <p>Nostrud eu veniam elit qui ea minim reprehenderit sit dolore cillum sit aute quis. Sit nostrud ad nisi est incididunt commodo ut ex reprehenderit excepteur. Irure id deserunt nulla sint dolore cillum fugiat ad ea tempor Lorem. Aliquip ex ad ullamco adipisicing enim duis. Exercitation elit sit est duis sint officia duis ad aliqua eiusmod reprehenderit amet reprehenderit consequat. Mollit occaecat elit eiusmod nulla officia laborum pariatur veniam ea do.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id='B' type="radio" name="nav">
      <label for='B'>B</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Elit irure consectetur officia laboris nulla sit laborum irure consectetur qui nisi id duis est. Cupidatat est cupidatat consequat quis ad non laboris duis ut laboris adipisicing incididunt. Laborum consectetur tempor ipsum ea quis sit laborum ullamco amet id consectetur id exercitation officia. Est dolor elit laborum nulla officia elit do nisi ex occaecat. Veniam mollit ut proident ut quis incididunt amet sunt ullamco velit. Nulla nostrud cillum ea sint sunt. Id Lorem duis nostrud irure quis et fugiat. Cupidatat duis dolore Lorem incididunt tempor ipsum. Nulla adipisicing nisi enim ea do deserunt officia ut labore excepteur aliqua.</p>
        <p>Elit irure consectetur officia laboris nulla sit laborum irure consectetur qui nisi id duis est. Cupidatat est cupidatat consequat quis ad non laboris duis ut laboris adipisicing incididunt. Laborum consectetur tempor ipsum ea quis sit laborum ullamco amet id consectetur id exercitation officia. Est dolor elit laborum nulla officia elit do nisi ex occaecat. Veniam mollit ut proident ut quis incididunt amet sunt ullamco velit. Nulla nostrud cillum ea sint sunt. Id Lorem duis nostrud irure quis et fugiat. Cupidatat duis dolore Lorem incididunt tempor ipsum. Nulla adipisicing nisi enim ea do deserunt officia ut labore excepteur aliqua.</p>
        <p>Elit irure consectetur officia laboris nulla sit laborum irure consectetur qui nisi id duis est. Cupidatat est cupidatat consequat quis ad non laboris duis ut laboris adipisicing incididunt. Laborum consectetur tempor ipsum ea quis sit laborum ullamco amet id consectetur id exercitation officia. Est dolor elit laborum nulla officia elit do nisi ex occaecat. Veniam mollit ut proident ut quis incididunt amet sunt ullamco velit. Nulla nostrud cillum ea sint sunt. Id Lorem duis nostrud irure quis et fugiat. Cupidatat duis dolore Lorem incididunt tempor ipsum. Nulla adipisicing nisi enim ea do deserunt officia ut labore excepteur aliqua.</p>
        <p>Elit irure consectetur officia laboris nulla sit laborum irure consectetur qui nisi id duis est. Cupidatat est cupidatat consequat quis ad non laboris duis ut laboris adipisicing incididunt. Laborum consectetur tempor ipsum ea quis sit laborum ullamco amet id consectetur id exercitation officia. Est dolor elit laborum nulla officia elit do nisi ex occaecat. Veniam mollit ut proident ut quis incididunt amet sunt ullamco velit. Nulla nostrud cillum ea sint sunt. Id Lorem duis nostrud irure quis et fugiat. Cupidatat duis dolore Lorem incididunt tempor ipsum. Nulla adipisicing nisi enim ea do deserunt officia ut labore excepteur aliqua.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Here is some extra text wooop</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you run this snippet you'll see that changing the radio button selected value will change the tab content just leaving it to have the styling you've already created applied.

Hope that can help you out and save you some stressing :)

Comment: Hey, thanks thats helpful. But i want those select circles removed and the text clickable, the button itself should be clickable without a selection circle. Also its gonna be hard to position the div absolute, as it needs to be responsive later on, like the sample I posted of the other page. I just cant get it to work :( Do you think you could help me out by building a button which is clickable without the selection circle which then shows the div on the right side which isnt positioned absolute? Is there a possibility? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hey user3204688, that shouldn't be a problem. The inputs styling can be adjusted to be like those in the links you submitted in your original post. I just put it together like I did to show it working using the same elements you had used so far.

Comment: Refer to my answer for updated code which removes the `radio` button check circles and styles like your example. Keeping it responsive won't be an issue. Your labels are set to `228px` in the link you submitted but as long as the `left` property of the `.content` class is the width of your labels, it will work at all viewport sizes.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I know, but the problem is, when the content is set to absolute positioning, the text in the content wont flow if I make the browser window smaller. The text in content needs to be set to relative in order to flow nicely when i lower the width of the browser window. But when I do this, the text, which belongs to the button on the left, will always start right next to the button and not at the top of the content area, which can only be accomplished when position is set to absolute with top: 0, right? Do you have an idea how i can solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I guess the only possibility would be if the content would be in a div box which is seperate from the container of the inputs, right? But I just dont know how to solve it. How can i show text in another div which is not in the same container as the input? Thanks

Comment: Hey @user3204668,  If you run the snippet now at full screen and resize the screen, the content text moves as would be expected. If it affects other elements in your page layout, one approach is that you can set a max height or an explicit height on the content panel or the outer root of the tabs to stop any text overflow into the layout. I've added this to the snippet. There will still be additional styling needed I imagine but this should help a bit. For an automatic height you could opt to make use of margins and floats instead. This may be a cleaner solution for what you need.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot jh3y,youre really helpful! :) But there is no possibility to create an extra content div where all the content is gonna be and connect them with the ids of the inputs? so like input1:checked ~ content#1 {display: block}? but the content being in another div outside the container of the input so you could make the content positioned relative? You know where Im going? Is there any possibility to not having to set the content absolute so I dont have to set a specific height to the content area or having to set a scrolling bar? Btw I added you on skype mabye its faster, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one version of a pure css accordion. This one works by clicking/checking the labels.  I have another that works on hover.

```css
   body { font-family: helvetica; }
   .accordion .row {
       width: 100%;
       position: relative;
       overflow: hidden;
       border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   }
   .accordion .row input { display: none; }
   .accordion .row .title { display: block; }
   
   .accordion .row .title, .accordion .row .body {
       padding: 10px;    
   }
   /* give the active row a darker border */
   .accordion .row input:checked {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
   }
   /* hide the body */
   .accordion .row .body {
    display: none;
   }
   /* show the description on hover */
   .accordion .row input:checked ~ .body {
    display: block;
   }
   /* give the active row title a background */
   .accordion .row input:checked + label {
    background-color: #cccccc;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="accordion">
   <div class="row">
    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab1" class="title">This is the title of row 1</label>
    <div class="body">This is the body of row 1. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab2" class="title">This is the title of row 2</label>
    <div class="body">This is the body of row 2. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs"><label for="tab3" class="title">This is the title of row 3</label>
    <div class="body">This is the body of row 3. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that works with css hover.

```css
   body { font-family: helvetica; }
   .accordion .row {
       width: 100%;
       position: relative;
       overflow: hidden;
       border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   }
   .accordion .row .title, .accordion .row .body {
       padding: 10px;    
   }
   /* give the active row a darker border */
   .accordion .row:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
   }
   /* hide the body */
   .accordion .row .body {
    display: none;
   }
   /* show the description on hover */
   .accordion .row:hover .body {
    display: block;
   }
   /* give the active row title a background */
   .accordion .row:hover .title {
    background-color: #cccccc;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="accordion">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="title">This is the title of row 1</div>
    <div class="body">This is the body of row 1. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="title">This is the title of row 2</div>
    <div class="body">This is the body of row 2. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="title">This is the title of row 3</div>
    <div class="body">This is the body of row 3. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks thats helpful. But i want those select circles removed and the text clickable, the button itself should be clickable without a selection circle. Also its gonna be hard to position the div absolute, as it needs to be responsive later on, like the sample I posted of the other page. I just cant get it to work :( Do you think you could help me out by building a button which is clickable without the selection circle which then shows the div on the right side which isnt positioned absolute? Is there a possibility? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I think your comment is for the first person who answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="heading">  
     <input name ="accordion" type="checkbox" id="1" class="btnControl"/>
     <label for="1" class="btn">Heading</label>   
   <div class="pan-content">
     content 1     
   </div>
</div>
<div class="heading">  
    <input name ="accordion" type="checkbox" id="2" class="btnControl"/>
     <label for="2" class="btn">Heading</label> 
   <div class="pan-content">
     content  2    
   </div>
</div>
<div class="heading">  
     <input name ="accordion" type="checkbox" id="3" class="btnControl"/>
     <label for="3" class="btn">Heading</label> 
   <div class="pan-content">
     content 3 
   </div>
</div>

.heading{
  width: 100px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:grey;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.heading .btn{  
   padding:5px;
}
.heading .pan-content{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  display:none;
}
.heading a:target ~.pan-content{
  display:block;
}
.btnControl{
  display:none;
}
.heading .btnControl:checked + label  ~.pan-content{
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjmh0pb5/7/